# How do I search a DataGridView by ID using a button?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` with `BookNumber`, `Title`, `AuthorNum`, `Price` and `quantityInStock`. I want to search rows by book number when the user presses a button. This is what I have, but it isn't working.

How can I show only the rows with the book number the user enters? Right now when I press enter no rows appear. Any help would be appreciated.

```
    Dim str As String
    str = InputBox("Enter an Book Number:", "Book Selection", "")
    TblBooksTableAdapter.Fill(BooksDataSet.tblBooks)

    Dim nums = (From n In BooksDataSet.tblBooks
         Where n.BookNumber = str
         Select n.BookNumber, n.Title, n.AuthorNum, n.Price, n.QuantityInStock).ToList

    DataGridView1.DataSource = BooksDataSet
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a 'DataView' IMHO to do this the easiest possible way.  Also DataGridViews work with DataTable better than well formed POCO sets so I generally set one up on the designer.  In this case I dragged and dropped a dataset I called 'ds' onto my design surface than create a 'tProducts' on the 'Tables' collection.  The code example would be like this:

```
Public Class DynamicFilterOnTwoTextItems

  Public Class ProductSku
    Public Property ProductId As Integer
    Public Property SkuID As Integer
    Public Property Description As String
  End Class

  Private _products As List(Of ProductSku) = New List(Of ProductSku)
  Private _initialLoadDone As Boolean = False

  Private Sub DynamicComboBoxDoubleFill_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    dgv.AutoGenerateColumns = False

    Dim products = New List(Of ProductSku)({
                                     New ProductSku With {.ProductId = 1, .SkuID = 1, .Description = "Offline"},
                                     New ProductSku With {.ProductId = 1, .SkuID = 2, .Description = "Offline2"},
                                     New ProductSku With {.ProductId = 2, .SkuID = 1, .Description = "Online"},
                                     New ProductSku With {.ProductId = 2, .SkuID = 2, .Description = "Online2"}
                                     })

    Dim s = ""
    For Each o In _products
      Dim row As DataRow = ds.Tables("tProducts").NewRow
      row("ProductId") = o.ProductId
      row("SkuID") = o.SkuID
      row("Desc") = o.Description
      ds.Tables("tProducts").Rows.Add(row)
    Next

    dgv.AutoGenerateColumns = False
    dgv.DataSource = ds.Tables("tProducts")

    _initialLoadDone = True
  End Sub

  Private Sub bFilter_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bFilter.Click

    Dim predicate = String.Empty

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(tsku.Text) Then
      predicate = $"ProductID = '{CInt(tPrd.Text)}'"
    Else
      predicate = $"ProductID = '{CInt(tPrd.Text)}' and SkuID = '{CInt(tsku.Text)}'"
    End If
    Dim dvProducts = New DataView(ds.Tables("tProducts"), predicate, "ProductID ASC", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)

    dgv.DataSource = dvProducts
  End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 

SearchTextBox.TextChanged

MainListView.Clear()
    DT = ExecuteQuery("SELECT * FROM Prac4 WHERE LastName LIKE '%" & SearchTextBox.Text & "%' OR FirstName Like '%" & SearchTextBox.Text & "%'")
    With MainListView
        .View = View.Details
        .GridLines = True
        .FullRowSelect = True
    End With
    MainListView.Columns.Add("EmpID", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
    MainListView.Columns.Add("FirstName", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
    MainListView.Columns.Add("LastName", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
    MainListView.Columns.Add("MiddleName", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
    MainListView.Columns.Add("DateHire", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
    MainListView.Columns.Add("EmpType", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
    MainListView.Columns.Add("Rate", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
    For i As Integer = 0 To DT.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim xItem As New ListViewItem(DT.Rows(i)("EmpID").ToString)
        xItem.SubItems.Add(DT.Rows(i)("FirstName").ToString)
        xItem.SubItems.Add(DT.Rows(i)("LastName").ToString)
        xItem.SubItems.Add(DT.Rows(i)("MiddleName").ToString)
        xItem.SubItems.Add(DT.Rows(i)("DateHire").ToString)
        xItem.SubItems.Add(DT.Rows(i)("EmpType").ToString)
        xItem.SubItems.Add(DT.Rows(i)("Rate").ToString)
        MainListView.Items.Add(xItem)
    Next
End Sub
```

Just try changing things in it.